# SSRS 2005 PDF Export Issue

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, export

Good Afternoon,

My report's page size is 8.5" by 11" with .5in margins all around.  When I preview the report in BIDS, it renders in portrait.  A change to landscape in page setup fixes this.

However, when I export to PDF and view it in Acrobat, the last column of my report rolls to page 2.  Instead of a 2 page report, I have a 4 page report with the last column on pages 2 and 4.

I've searched this site and others and could not find any fixes for this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in layout mode, what is the width of your report?  If your page size is 8.5" with .5" margins all the way around, the maximum width of your report is 7.5".

I've run into the same type of issue before, and it turned out that the width of my report was just a smidge over 7.5".

Comment: I changed the width to 7.5 under Layout->PageSize->Width.  Re-exported, and now 2 columns are hanging off to a new page in the PDF.

Comment: I'm talking about the size of the layout on the grid in the designer.  There should be a ruler across the top of the designer, and you want to make sure that the grid doesn't extend past 7.5".

Comment: I've done that, and am still having the original issue.  That is, one column is forcing over to its own page.  I've removed 2 hidden fields from laoyout view, resized columns to no avail.

Comment: Are you running into the physical limits of the printer WRT unprintable margins?  A .3" unprintable margin, respected as the limit of your form, will push a 7.5"-wide print area with designated .5" borders onto a new page. (.3 +.5 + 7.5 +.5 +.3 = 9.1")  Some printer setups need to be told to ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Interactive Size and Page Size properly for the report